# Android autofill enters the same info multiple times, when reusing layout

Tags: android

I have a fragment in which I reuse the same layout multiple times. The layout has two EditText fields, one for name and one for email. In other words the view lets you put in multiple contacts at the same time, how many is optional. What happens is:

1. The user presses one of the fields, say the email field, and Android's built in autofill feature shows a suggestion.
2. User presses the option, a stored email address.
3. The email address is then entered multiple times by the autofill function, into each of the reused layouts. 
   Say I have three views for contact information, then each of the three email fields will receive the autofilled email address, clearing anything that was before.

I want it to be entered only into the currently selected field, is there any way to control this?

```
LinearLayout contactsListLayout;

for (Contact contact : contacts) {
          ContactView view = new ContactView(context, contact);
          contactsListLayout.addView(view);
      }
```

---

ContactView.java

```
public class ContactView extends RelativeLayout  {
...
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.contact_view);
     }

...
}
```

---

contact_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <EditText
          android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
          android:inputType="textCapSentences"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSearch"
          android:hint="Name"/>

     <EditText
          android:id="@+id/emailEdit" 
          android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="E-mail Address"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Looking at [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize), I guess you could try dynamically setting the `importantForAutoFill` attribute: when one of the input groups is activated, set the attribute to `no` for all other fragments.

Comment: A bit of a hack, but could work :) Will try it. Maybe the reverse though, set it to "no" as default, and "yes" when an input is activated.

Comment: Hacky indeed. It depends: if the attribute is checked before you can react to the input event, the autofill suggestions may not be displayed. Please report if it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple email input fields in a layout. When one of the input fields gets focus, autofill options shows up. And if we choose one of the options, autofill service pastes the same value to all input fields even if its focused or not.

I tried manipulating the `importantForAutoFill` flags of my views, to autoFill only the focused input field, but that didn't work.

So in my custom component, I've overridden the `autoFill()` method, to make it work only if the view is focused. If not, suppressed the autoFill action.

```
override fun autofill(value: AutofillValue?) {
    if (hasFocus()) {
        super.autofill(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then the user fills the editText with his email address, you can store it in SQL database, after that user goes to the second view and there will be another field for email address. So at that time your app gets String value(email address) that you inserted into your SQL database , and fills in the editText automatically.

Hopefully my answer helps you.

Here are some links for setting up SQL database:

1. [Android SQLite Database with Examples](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-sqlite-database-with-examples)
2. [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, but thanks anyway :)